# How can I list the privileges associated to a custom created role in SQL Azure database?

Tags: azure, sql

I have created a custom role in a SQL Azure DB, granting a couple of privileges. How can I, at a later time, list the privileges associated to this custom role? We need this for an audit on the DB security.